# Why in cluster PSQL with 3 node one node - sync_state= sync and next node sync_state= async?

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, synchronous, database-cluster

I want PostgreSQL Synchronous Streaming Database Replication Status = sync.

I deployed PostgreSQL cluster with 3 node and write sync type - Synchronous. But when i check type `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication;`
 - i get first node - sync_state=`sync`,and other `async`, what is ? Why its two different type ?

Comment: `show synchronous_standby_names` on master?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With synchronous streaming replication in PostgreSQL, the commit on the primary is delayed until one of the standby servers has received the corresponding WAL information (the exact meaning of this is configurable with [`synchronous_commit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT)).

The standby server who first confirms the reception of the WAL information is the one with `sync_state` `'sync'`, the other will be `'async'`.

Comment: But i think in new version 9.6 may be 3 node with sync .
What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, but only if [`synchronous_standby_names`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES) is configured appropriately, i.e. starts with a number before a parenthesis. Note that if you have a synchronous replication system where *all* of the standbys are synchronous, your availibility will *sink* - if any of the standbys fail, the whole system becomes inoperational.